# Percentage does not work with FlatList render item when horizontal is true

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I would like to use the screen's width on the render item of the `horizontal` FlatList. However, it does not work as expected. When the `horizontal` is false, the percentage value works. But when the `horizontal` is true, the percentage value does not work.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  _renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          height: 100,
        }}>
        <Text>{item.key}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={[{ key: 1 }, { key: 2 }, { key: 3 }]}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          horizontal={true}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[Snack link when the FlatList is horizontal](https://snack.expo.io/BJIZRf9rM)

[Snack link when the FlatList is NOT horizontal](https://snack.expo.io/HJStCG5rz)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I remember someone mentionning something like that. Using Dimensions works here. See here: https://snack.expo.io/H1-wnC5HM

I rather solve it with flex or percentage but well.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the only way to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't there a way with percentages? I mean what if the container doesn't fit the whole screen, this wouldn't work as the parent would not have the correct width (not equal to screen width).

Comment: Percentages of width do work in some cases. This was just specific to scrollviews. And if that does not work, you can always use onLayout prop of the View, which will give you the width of the parent and you can use that value to set the style of the child. If this does not help you, post a question and post the link